# How to place a THREE.js plane on the surface of a sphere?

Tags: javascript, three.js, 3d, geometry

I'm new to Threejs / 3D graphics. I would like to know how to lay a plane of any given height and width on the surface area of a sphere. something like this
[example image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PxwHJ.png)

Comment: As a starting point: https://discourse.threejs.org/t/how-to-curve-planes-such-that-each-child-plane-curvature-matches-it-parents/35596/13

Comment: @prisoner849 the only issue with this code is a new plane gets smaller if I wanted add another position for ex buildPlane(-4,1,2,6,6). This wouldn't work if I want to use buildPlane to build a sphere around the red sphere which is my ultimate goal. Think of it like this. I would like to use 4 planes to make 1 large plane then I would repeat this for ever side to build a cube and then turn that cube into a sphere by calling a function that takes a list of the 4 small planes and bend them. So that function would need be called 6x for each side

Comment: So what have you tried?

Comment: @prisoner849  It was my misunderstanding of what was being shown to me. I was able to build each side of the cube with the default values you have set. The problem I'm having is increasing the radius of a sphere to a large value and increasing each planes width, height, in turn shifting the position of each plane causes the btnBend function to move the outer planes inside the red sphere when pressed [example](https://codepen.io/miguelmyers8/pen/qBVwYje). setting v3.setLength() to some large value fixes it. can you explain what this method does in relation to my problem?

Answer (score 0):

You can intersect the points of the plane to the surface of the sphere.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).